# Visual C# Directory.GetDirectories Issue - "The specified server cannot perform the requested operation"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, macos, osx-mavericks

I'm having an issue when trying to call the `Directory.GetDirectories` function for a mapped Mac directory.  A few weeks ago (and for about a year), the function worked with no issues.  After upgrading the Mac to OS X Mavericks, the function call throws an exception:

> The specified server cannot perform the requested operation.

I'm able to access the directory with no issues from windows explorer.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Here is the snippet:

```
if (Directory.Exists(rootDirectory))  // Success here...
{
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory);  // Exception error here!!!
    ...
}
```

Update: I'm able to successfully call the "GetDirectories" function on directories **within** the problematic directory.  The problematic directory contains 758 directories, and those under it contain ~20 max.  I'm doubting that 758 directories is hitting a maximum count, but who knows?  I hoping to not have to try to test an upper limit on directory count if the answer is more obvious than that, but I may have to do this to debug...

Thanks!

Comment: Any code you wish to share?

Comment: Hi neo, I've added a code snippet.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your C# code is fine. You could try replacing `Directory.GetDirectories` with `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` (MS says EnumerateDirectories is more efficient), but I doubt it'll help.

The problem is on the OSX side. In ver. 10.9 they replaced SMB1 with the broken implementation of SMB2, which currently only supports 32 files/subfolders in a folder. [Here's the discussion](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=12481).

There're workarounds to access Windows shares from OS X, but not the vice versa. I don't think anything could be done until Apple will fix their OSX..

Comment: Thank you very much!  Exactly what I was looking for.  I'll wait for OSX to be fixed.